# Como fazer com que o sistema exiba uma mensagem de erro quando não for número?

Tags: python

Como fazer com que o sistema retorne alguma mensagem do tipo "Este valor deve ser numérico" no problema abaixo? (menu um e dois já foram definidos, esse é apenas um corte)

```
print("MENU PRINCIPAL")
while True:
    esc_menu = int(input("\n1) Ir para o menu um. \n"
                         "2) Ir para o menu dois.\n "
                         "\nEscolha uma opção: "))
    if esc_menu == 1:
        menu_um()
    if esc_menu == 2:
        menu_dois()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A classe `int` levanta uma exceção do tipo `ValueError` quando o valor a ser convertido para inteiro não é numérico, portanto, para garantir que o valor entrado pelo usuário seja numérico, basta tratar a exceção.

```
try:
    esc_menu = int(input("..."))
except ValueError:
    print("O valor deve ser um número inteiro")
```

Como se trata de um menu, você poderia fazer algo como:

```
def menu_um(): print("Menu 1")
def menu_dois(): print("Menu 2")

message = """
1) Ir para o menu um.
2) Ir para o menu dois.

Escolha uma opção: 
"""

menu = {
    1: menu_um,
    2: menu_dois
}

print("Menu")

while True:
    try:
        esc_menu = int(input(message))
        menu[esc_menu]()
    except ValueError:
        print("O valor deve ser um número inteiro")
    except KeyError:
        print("Opção inválida")
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ImpracticalAmusingAmericanlobster)</sup>

Como o Python não possui a estrutura `switch/case`, você pode utilizar um dicionário para armazenar todas as funções e, assim, evitar um grande número de `if` seguidos. Veja que neste caso eu criei o dicionário `menu` e invoquei a devida função fazendo `menu[esc_menu]()`. Também defini a *string* `message` com o texto a ser exibido no menu, pois, como são múltiplas linhas, utilizar a *string* entre aspas triplas facilitará a leitura e manutenção do código.

Answer (score 3):

Caso seja apenas inteiros, você pode utilizar a função `isdigit()` ou `isnumeric()` porém não poderá converter a entrada em *int*. Veja:

> [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit): Retornar verdadeiro se todos os caracteres na seqüência de caracteres forem alfabéticos e houver pelo menos um personagem, falso caso contrário. (Tradução livre)
>
> [isnumeric()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.isnumeric): Retornar verdadeiro se houver apenas caracteres numéricos em S, Falso caso contrário. Os caracteres numéricos incluem caracteres de dígitos e todos os caracteres que possuem a propriedade do valor numérico Unicode. (Tradução livre)

```
print("MENU PRINCIPAL")
while True:
  esc_menu = input("\n1) Ir para o menu um. \n"
  "2) Ir para o menu dois.\n "
  "\nEscolha uma opção: ")
  if esc_menu.isdigit() == False:
    print("Este valor deve ser numérico")
    
  if esc_menu == "1":
    print("OPCAO 01")
  if esc_menu == "2":
    print("OPCAO 02")
```

> Lembrando que funcionara apenas para inteiros.
> Podem haver jeitos mais fáceis.
> isdigit() veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CuteMeanCowbird)
> isnumeric() veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FirebrickFancyFlyinglemur)

#### Referência

- [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)
- [isnumeric()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.isnumeric)

> Estas funções indicam se uma determinada *string* é totalmente formada por números, se a *string* conter ao menos um caractere que invalide essa condição, elas retornarão `False`.

Comment: Estas funções indicam se uma determinada *string* é totalmente formada por números, se a *string* conter ao menos um caractere que invalide essa condição, elas retornarão `False`.