# Método de escolha com while

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Tenho duas opções e o programa deve dizer qual foi escolhido, caso a entrada seja errada deve pedir para repetir o pedido.

Problemas: Opção 2 repete 2 vezes até acertar. A opção 1, não diz o um nome que não esta no *script*

```
print('''Choice your number
[1] Banana
[2] Apple ''')

    option = int(input('Your option: '))
    while option != 1 and 2:
        print('Try again')
        option = int(input('Your option: '))
        if option == 1:
            print('Banana choiced')
        elif option == 2:
            print('Apple choiced')
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer com que o sistema exiba uma mensagem de erro quando não for número?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256342/como-fazer-com-que-o-sistema-exiba-uma-mensagem-de-erro-quando-n%c3%a3o-for-n%c3%bamero)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss embora pareça mesmo, não acho que seja porque ela tem uma peculiaridade de que as opções válidas são testadas. Eu achei até que poderia ser o mesmo caso da que eu respondi anteriormente, mas é um pouco diferente.

Comment: Sou suspeito para comentar, mais certamente não são.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É mais fácil do que parece:

```
print('''Choice your number
[1] Banana
[2] Apple ''')
while True:
    option = int(input('Your option: '))
    if option == 1:
        print('Banana choiced')
        break
    elif option == 2:
        print('Apple choiced')
        break
    print('Try again')
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ApVESe). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/iqhvaufe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Validation.py)

Como você verifica as opções aceitas e se uma delas for digitada deve encerrar a execução é só encerrar o laço quando entrar em uma delas (`break`). Se não entrar nas opções permitidas e validadas com `if` ele só fica no laço indefinidamente até digitarem o que vale.

Comment: realmente é simples, estou a dar os meus primeiros passos em Python. agradeço ajuda.