# Erro de sintaxe no código Python. O que é?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("**************")
print("Seja Bem Vindo")
print("**************")
numero_secreto = 65
chute = input("Digite um numero:")
print("Você digitou: ",chute)
if numero_secreto == chute
    print("você acertou")
else
    print("Você errou, Tente novamente")
```

Eu não entendo o porque dele não rodar

Comment: Você leu as mensagens de erro? Nelas tem escrito o que está errado.

Comment: Eu li mas não entendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há erros de sintaxe e de lógica. Os erros de sintaxe são fáceis de corrigir: o interpretador te mostra uma mensagem de erro apontando exatamente o local e o erro.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "python", line 7
>     if chute == numero_secreto
>                              ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Faltou os dois pontos, `:`, após o `if`.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "python", line 9
>     else
>        ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Faltou os dois pontos após o `else`.

Com essas correções seu código ainda não funcionará, pois o retorno da função `input` será sempre uma *string*, então você estará comparando uma *string* com um inteiro, o que não faz sentido e nunca será verdadeiro. Como deseja ler um inteiro, precisa converter o valor como tal fazendo:

```
chute = int(input("Digite um numero:"))
```

Porém, desta forma, se o usuário entrar com qualquer valor que não seja numérico, uma exceção será disparada. Para resolver este problema, leia:

[Como fazer com que o sistema exiba uma mensagem de erro quando não for número?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/256342/5878)

Comment: Ok, valeu pelo conhecimento

Answer (score 2):

Erro de ***sintaxe*** faltou colocar dois pontos no `if` e no `else`

```
print("**************")
print("Seja Bem Vindo")
print("**************")
numero_secreto = 65
chute = input("Digite um numero:")
print("Você digitou: ",chute)
if chute == numero_secreto:
    print("você acertou")
else:
    print("Você errou, Tente novamente")
```

[Veja exemplo OnLine](https://ideone.com/aWzxjo)

Exemplo de `if` com `else`

```
if expression:
   statement(s)
else:
   statement(s)
```

mas, ***a comparação contem também problemas***, ou coloca `numero_secreto = "65"` a sua comparação vai funcionar porque o `input` retorna um valor texto, ou então coloque a `int` (`int(input("Digite um numero:")`) e deixe o `numero_secreto = 65` também como inteiro para que possa comparar e não ter problemas na comparação.

<sup>***Fonte:*** [Python IF...ELIF...ELSE Statements](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm)</sup>

Comment: Ata, valeu cara

Answer (score 0):

Apos if e else coloque : ,e quando for usar input e o resultado esperado é um numero inteiro, utilize a função int()

Corrigido:

```
print("**************")
print("Seja Bem Vindo")
print("**************")
numero_secreto = 65
chute = int(input("Digite um numero:"))
print("Você digitou: ",chute)
if numero_secreto == chute:
    print("você acertou")
else:
    print("Você errou, Tente novamente")
```