# Python, porcentagem de valores (resultado)

Tags: python

é o seguinte eu preciso fazer que o programa mostre a porcentagem dos votos, só que se eu iniciar a variavel com zero não dá, porque o programa diz que divisão por zero não dá, porém se eu iniciar com 1, a conta vai dar errado, alguem pode me dar uma luz ? o programa mostra quantos votos teve determinado sistema operacional e a porcentagem em relação ao total.

```
listaWindows = []
listaUNIX = []
listaLinux = []
listaNetware = []
listaMacos = []
listaOutro = []
contW = contU = contL = contN = contM = contO = porcenW = porcenU = porcenL = porcenN = porcenM = porcenO = 0
soma = 1
while True:
    print('''
    1 - Windows Server
    2 - UNIX
    3 - Linux
    4 - Netware
    5 - Mac OS
    6 - Outro''')
    opcao = int(input("Informe a opção desejada: "))
    if opcao == 0:
        break
    while opcao > 6 or opcao < 1:
        opcao = int(input("Opção invalida, digite a opção novamente: "))
    if opcao == 1:
        listaWindows.append(contW)
        contW += 1
        porcenW = (contW / soma) * 100
    if opcao == 2:
        listaUNIX.append(contU)
        contU += 1
        porcenU = (contU / soma) * 100
    if opcao == 3:
        listaLinux.append(contL)
        contL += 1
        porcenL = (contL / soma) * 100
    if opcao == 4:
        listaNetware.append(contN)
        contN += 1
        porcenN = (contN / soma) * 100
    if opcao == 5:
        listaMacos.append(contM)
        contM += 1
        porcenM =  (contM / soma) * 100
    if opcao == 6:
        listaOutro.append(contO)
        contO += 1
        porcenO = (contO / soma) * 100
    soma = contW + contU + contL + contN + contM + contO
print(f'''
        Votos  %
Windows: {contW}    {porcenW:.2f}
UNIX:    {contU}    {porcenU:.2f}
Linux:   {contL}    {porcenL:.2f}
Netware: {contN}    {porcenN:.2f}
Mac      {contM}    {porcenM:.2f}
Outro    {contO}    {porcenO:.2f}''')
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta resposta é baseada nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256348/60376) dada pelo [*Anderson Carlos Woss*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss). Você pode utilizar um dicionário para armazenar todas as opções:

```
opcoes = { 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0 }
```

fazendo assim, evita um grande número de `if` seguidos. Defina uma lista com os nomes dos sistemas:

```
sistemas = [ 'Windows', 'UNIX', 'Linux', 'Netware', 'Mac OS', 'Outro' ]
```

a cada opção informada pelo usuário, faça o incremento no valor da opção selecionada `opcoes[opcao] += 1`.

A classe `int` levanta uma exceção do tipo `ValueError` quando o valor a ser convertido para inteiro não é numérico, portanto, para garantir que o valor entrado pelo usuário seja numérico, basta tratar a exceção.

```
try:
  opcao = int(input(menu))
except ValueError:
  print("O valor deve ser um número inteiro")
```

o método `porcentagem`

```
def porcentagem(votos, total):
  return (votos / total) * 100 if total > 0 else 0
```

Para verificar a porcentagem de cada opção, fazemos a soma de todos os valores do dicionário:

```
total = sum(opcoes.values())
```

Para evitar repetições desnecessárias, percorremos as chaves do dicionário e imprimimos o nome do sistema, o número de votos e a porcentagem:

```
print('Sistema ', ' Votos', ' Porcentagem')
print('----------------------------')
for chave, valor in opcoes.items():
  espacos = ' ' * (8 - (len(sistemas[chave-1])))
  print(sistemas[chave-1], espacos, valor, ' ' * 4, porcentagem(valor, total))
        # Nome do sistema           # Votos         # Porcentagem
```

a string `espacos` e `' ' * 4` servem apenas para melhorar a visualização.

#### Código completo

```
opcoes = { 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0 }
sistemas = [ 'Windows', 'UNIX', 'Linux', 'Netware', 'Mac OS', 'Outro' ]

menu = """
1 - Windows Server
2 - UNIX
3 - Linux
4 - Netware
5 - Mac OS
6 - Outro

Escolha uma opção:"""
while True:
  try:
    opcao = int(input(menu))
    if opcao == 0: break
    opcoes[opcao] += 1
  except ValueError:
    print("O valor deve ser um número inteiro")
  except KeyError:
    print("Opção inválida")

def porcentagem(votos, total):
  return (votos / total) * 100 if total > 0 else 0

total = sum(opcoes.values())

print('Sistema ', ' Votos', ' Porcentagem')
print('----------------------------')
for chave, valor in opcoes.items():
  espacos = ' ' * (8 - (len(sistemas[chave-1])))
  print(sistemas[chave-1], espacos, valor, ' ' * 4, porcentagem(valor, total))
        # Nome do sistema           # Votos         # Porcentagem
```

Veja [funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/stack-293160)

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas alterações no código, não havia necessidade da utilização de listas. É possível simplificar ainda mais, mas como não é objetivo, vamos ao código.

Fiz a soma de todos contadores, e no final criei método para pegar a porcentagem, nesse método faço uma verificação se o valor total não é igual a **0**, evitando que gere exceção.

```
contW = contU = contL = contN = contM = contO = 0

while True:
    print('''
    1 - Windows Server
    2 - UNIX
    3 - Linux
    4 - Netware
    5 - Mac OS
    6 - Outro''')
    opcao = int(input("Informe a opção desejada: "))
    if opcao == 0:
        break
    while opcao > 6 or opcao < 1:
        opcao = int(input("Opção invalida, digite a opção novamente: "))        
    if opcao == 1:
        contW = contW + 1
    if opcao == 2:
        contU = contU + 1
    if opcao == 3:
        contL = contL + 1
    if opcao == 4:
        contN = contN + 1
    if opcao == 5:
        contM = contM + 1
    if opcao == 6:
        contO = contO + 1

def percent(indicador, total):
    if total is not 0:
        return (indicador / total) * 100
    else:
        return 0

total = contW + contU + contL + contN + contM + contO
porcenW = percent(contW, total)
porcenU = percent(contU, total)
porcenL = percent(contL, total)
porcenN = percent(contN, total)
porcenM = percent(contM, total)
porcenO = percent(contO, total)

print(f'''
        Votos  %
Windows: {contW}    {porcenW:.2f}
UNIX:    {contU}    {porcenU:.2f}
Linux:   {contL}    {porcenL:.2f}
Netware: {contN}    {porcenN:.2f}
Mac      {contM}    {porcenM:.2f}
Outro    {contO}    {porcenO:.2f}''')
```

Comment: Obrigado, desse jeito funcionou

Comment: @punkoco Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 