# Problemas com o comando 'continue' ou 'while' em Python

Tags: python, while

Então, tava fazendo alguns exercícios em python, linguagem na qual estou aprendendo a programar, e me aparenta que o fluxo de execução não está seguindo de forma correta.

```
# Converte distancia

def mettocent(met):
    cent = met * 100
    return cent

def centtomet(cent):
    met = cent / 100
    return met

def mettokil(met):
    kil = met / 1000
    return kil

def kiltomet(kil):
    met= kil * 1000
    return met

def centtokil(cent):
    kil = cent / 100000
    return kil

def kiltocent(kil):
    cent = kil * 100000
    return cent

escolha = True

while escolha == True:

    print('Escolha uma opção de conversão:')
    print('1 Metros para centimetros\n2 Centimetros para metros\n3 Metros para quilometros')
    print('4 Quilometros para metros\n5 Centimetros para quilometros\n6 Quilometros para centimetros\n')
    escolha = int(input())

    if escolha > 6:
        print("Opção inválida, digite novamente")
        continue

    dist = float(input("Digite a distância a ser convertida:"))

    if escolha == 1:
        print(mettocent(dist), "centimentros")
        break
    elif escolha == 2:
        print(centtomet(dist), "metros")
        break
    elif escolha == 3:
        print(mettokil(dist), "quilometros")
        break
    elif escolha == 4:
        print(kiltomet(dist), "metros")
        break
    elif escolha == 5:
        print(centtokil(dist), "quilometros")
        break
    elif escolha == 6:
        print(kiltocent(dist), "centimentros")
        break
```

O que acontece é que quando dentro da repetição, ele verifica que o valor da escolha é maior que 6, e até onde sei, em python, tudo que diferente de 0 é True, não volta para o inicio da repetição, mas sai dela, dando isso de saída, por exemplo:

```
Escolha uma opção de conversão:
1 Metros para centimetros
2 Centimetros para metros
3 Metros para quilometros
4 Quilometros para Metros
5 Centimetros para quilometros
6 Quilometros para centimetros
7

Opção inválida, digite novamente

Process finished with exit code 0
```

(Sei que podem existir melhores formas de fazer esse programa, e que as funções não são necessárias, mas to adaptando o que já aprendi até então num exercício que pedia apenas pra "converter metros pra centimentros")

Comment: Consegui contornar o problema atribuindo True para 'escolha' se cair em 'escolha > 6'
Mas ainda queria entender o porque do problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *e até onde sei, em python, tudo que diferente de 0 é True*

Sua premissa está errada.

No Python, qualquer número diferente de zero será considerado um valor verdadeiro, mas não necessariamente igual a `True`. São os chamados *truthy values*, caso queira pesquisar mais sobre.

```
if 6:
    print('Ok')  # Exibe, pois 6 é um truthy value
```

Porém, se fizer:

```
if 6 == True:
    print('Ok')  # Não exibe, pois 6 não é igual a True
```

Inclusive, no Python, o tipo booleano é uma especialização do tipo inteiro, onde o valor `True` é igual a `int(1)` e o `False` é igual a `int(0)`. Por isso, ao fazer `True == 1`, o resultado será verdadeiro, mas `True == 6` será falso.

Para contornar isso, você pode trocar `while escolha == true` para `while true` apenas.

Outros detalhes sobre a implementação deste problema eu já comentei em:

- [Como fazer com que o sistema exiba uma mensagem de erro quando não for número?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/256342/5878)
- [Aceitar somente numéricos no input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244764/5878)

Comment: Valeuu! Bem que meu professor não explica as coisas por completo rs

Comment: @NelsonP seus melhores professores estão aqui, hehehe