# Como fazer o codigo python rodar de novo após executar algo?

Tags: python

Entao, não sou muito experiente no python e estava tentando fazer um programinha de terminal para organizar livros.. segue uma parte do codigo:

```
#sql
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('teste.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dados(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, \
               nome_livro TEXT NOT NULL,nome_autor TEXT NOT NULL,pagina INTEGER NOT NULL,pagina_total INTEGER NOT NULL,\
               nota REAL,note TEXT);")
#principal
print('Bem vindo ao seu contador virtual. (help para ajuda)')
opcao = input('O que deseja? ')
if opcao.upper().strip() == 'HELP':
    print('Ola, estou aqui para te ajudar sempre que precisar :)')
    print('Suas opções são: ')
    print('"Adicionar"=> para adicionar um novo livro.')
    print('"Avaliar"=> para dar uma nota a um livro.')
    print('"Atualizar"=> para atualizar as informações de algum livro.')
    print('"Remover"=> para apagar os dados de algum livro.')
    print('"Listar"=> para mostrar as informações de todos os livros registrados.')
    print('"Status"=> para mostrar informações sobre um livro especifico.')
    opcao = input('Digite agora sua opção: ')
if opcao.upper().strip() == 'ADICIONAR':
    nome_livro = input('Digite o nome do livro: ')
    nome_autor = input('Digite o nome do autor: ')
    numero_pagina = int(input('Digite a pagina que você está: '))
    numero_total = int(input('Digite o numero total de paginas: '))
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dados (nome_livro, nome_autor, pagina, pagina_total) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', (nome_livro, nome_autor, numero_pagina, numero_total))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    input('Livro adicionado com sucesso, aperte qualquer tecla para fechar o programa. ')
elif opcao.upper().strip() == 'AVALIAR':
    cursor.execute('SELECT id,nome_livro FROM dados')
    for linha in cursor.fetchall():
        print(linha)
    id_nota = int(input('Digite o numero do livro que deseja avaliar: '))
```

Então, da forma que eu fiz a cada ação que o usuario fizer o programa precisa fechar e abrir de novo o programa para fazer outra coisa, mas eu gostaria que depois de qualquer ação ele pudesse realizar outra sem precisar fechar. Eu não sei como faz isso e gostaria de ajuda.. Obrigado.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como fazer com que o sistema exiba uma mensagem de erro quando não for número?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256342/como-fazer-com-que-o-sistema-exiba-uma-mensagem-de-erro-quando-n%c3%a3o-for-n%c3%bamero)

Comment: Você por exemplo colocar a execulão do seu programa em um laço  `while True:`  e adicionar uma opção que finalize o programa, ou seja, quando a condição cair nessa opção você dá uma instrução como `sys,exit()` ou `break`, dependendo do que você desejar. Isso ajuda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazer isso:

- Loop com infinito com ***while True***

> só lembrando que deste modo você precisa adicionar uma ***opção ou condição de saída*** que quebre o loop com o comando ***break*** caso contrário ele vai continuar rodando até que você o pare manualmente.

```
while True: # Começa o loop

    # Principal
    print('Bem vindo ao seu contador virtual. (help para ajuda)')
    opcao = input('O que deseja? ')

    if opcao.upper().strip() == 'HELP':
        print('Ola, estou aqui para te ajudar sempre que precisar :)')
        print('Suas opções são: ')
        print('"Adicionar"=> para adicionar um novo livro.')
        print('"Avaliar"=> para dar uma nota a um livro.')
        print('"Atualizar"=> para atualizar as informações de algum livro.')
        print('"Remover"=> para apagar os dados de algum livro.')
        print('"Listar"=> para mostrar as informações de todos os livros registrados.')
        print('"Status"=> para mostrar informações sobre um livro especifico.')
        print('"Sair"=> Encerra o loop')

    elif opcao.upper().strip() == 'ADICIONAR':
        nome_livro = input('Digite o nome do livro: ')
        nome_autor = input('Digite o nome do autor: ')
        numero_pagina = int(input('Digite a pagina que você está: '))
        numero_total = int(input('Digite o numero total de paginas: '))
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dados (nome_livro, nome_autor, pagina, pagina_total) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', (nome_livro, nome_autor, numero_pagina, numero_total))
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        
    elif opcao.upper().strip() == 'AVALIAR':
        cursor.execute('SELECT id,nome_livro FROM dados')
        for linha in cursor.fetchall():
            print(linha)
        id_nota = int(input('Digite o numero do livro que deseja'))

    # Opção de saída para terminar o loop
    elif opcao.upper().strip() == "SAIR":
        break
```

- Utilização de função

> Além de dar mais controle sobre o loop, as funções podem ser chamadas em outros lugares do código e serem executadas novamente.

```
def contador_virtual():

    # Principal
    print('Bem vindo ao seu contador virtual. (help para ajuda)')
    opcao = input('O que deseja? ')

    if opcao.upper().strip() == 'HELP':
        print('Ola, estou aqui para te ajudar sempre que precisar :)')
        print('Suas opções são: ')
        print('"Adicionar"=> para adicionar um novo livro.')
        print('"Avaliar"=> para dar uma nota a um livro.')
        print('"Atualizar"=> para atualizar as informações de algum livro.')
        print('"Remover"=> para apagar os dados de algum livro.')
        print('"Listar"=> para mostrar as informações de todos os livros registrados.')
        print('"Status"=> para mostrar informações sobre um livro especifico.')
        print('"Sair"=> Encerra o loop')

    elif opcao.upper().strip() == 'ADICIONAR':
        nome_livro = input('Digite o nome do livro: ')
        nome_autor = input('Digite o nome do autor: ')
        numero_pagina = int(input('Digite a pagina que você está: '))
        numero_total = int(input('Digite o numero total de paginas: '))
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dados (nome_livro, nome_autor, pagina, pagina_total) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', (nome_livro, nome_autor, numero_pagina, numero_total))
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        
    elif opcao.upper().strip() == 'AVALIAR':
        cursor.execute('SELECT id,nome_livro FROM dados')
        for linha in cursor.fetchall():
            print(linha)
        id_nota = int(input('Digite o numero do livro que deseja'))

    # Opção de saída para terminar o loop
    elif opcao.upper().strip() == "SAIR":
        return True # Finaliza a função

    contador_virtual() # Roda a função novamente caso ela não tenha entrado na condição de saída

contador_virtual() # Chamando função para ser rodada
```

> É importante ressaltar que o ***return True*** vai encerrar a função no momento em que for chamado (Ou seja vai terminar a função sem rodar o resto das linhas que a compõe) sem fechar o seu programa como vou falar abaixo.

- Sys.exit()

> Como dito antes nos comentários pelo ***Lucas Maraal*** você pode adicionar um ***sys.exit()*** para encerrar o programa completamente.

> Vou apenas adicionar uma nova condição dentro da função e importar o módulo sys:

```
    elif opcao.upper().strip() == "FECHAR":
        import sys # Recomendo importar junto do sqlite3 lá no começo do código
        sys.exit()
```

- Você pode usar um loop ***for***

> Permite que você execute uma sequência de linhas em uma quantidade limitada de vezes. (Pode receber um comando de ***break*** para encerra-lá mais cedo)

> O ***i*** dentro do código pode ser substituído por qualquer outra coisa ***menos números*** e o ***range(5)*** indica quantas vezes você vai rodar o loop.

```
for i in range(5):
    # Principal
    print('Bem vindo ao seu contador virtual. (help para ajuda)')
    opcao = input('O que deseja? ')

    if opcao.upper().strip() == 'HELP':
        print('Ola, estou aqui para te ajudar sempre que precisar :)')
        print('Suas opções são: ')
        print('"Adicionar"=> para adicionar um novo livro.')
        print('"Avaliar"=> para dar uma nota a um livro.')
        print('"Atualizar"=> para atualizar as informações de algum livro.')
        print('"Remover"=> para apagar os dados de algum livro.')
        print('"Listar"=> para mostrar as informações de todos os livros registrados.')
        print('"Status"=> para mostrar informações sobre um livro especifico.')
        print('"Sair"=> Encerra o loop')

    elif opcao.upper().strip() == 'ADICIONAR':
        nome_livro = input('Digite o nome do livro: ')
        nome_autor = input('Digite o nome do autor: ')
        numero_pagina = int(input('Digite a pagina que você está: '))
        numero_total = int(input('Digite o numero total de paginas: '))
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dados (nome_livro, nome_autor, pagina, pagina_total) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', (nome_livro, nome_autor, numero_pagina, numero_total))
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        
    elif opcao.upper().strip() == 'AVALIAR':
        cursor.execute('SELECT id,nome_livro FROM dados')
        for linha in cursor.fetchall():
            print(linha)
        id_nota = int(input('Digite o numero do livro que deseja'))

    # Opção de saída para terminar o loop
    elif opcao.upper().strip() == "SAIR":
        break
```

Ou você pode combinar o método de ***funções*** com os ***loops*** ***for e while***

- Utilizando ***while***

> É um loop inifito deste modo, porém você pode adicionar alguma condição no lugar do ***True*** para controlar melhor quantas vezes ele vai executar as linhas dentro dele.

> Ou você pode só colocar um ***if*** logo depois de rodar a função que permita que o loop seja quebrado colocando um ***break*** dentro dele.

```
while True: # Ou alguma outra condição qualquer
    contador_virtual()
```

- Utilizando ***for***

> Vou rodar a função 5 vezes aqui por exemplo:

```
for i in range(5):
    contador_virtual()
```